# GAE, Python: How to define db object classes in only one place?

Tags: python, class, google-app-engine

I have a main.py which contains class definitions for objects that are fetched from db and displayed.

I also have a scrape.py that fetches these same sorts of objects from the web, and stores them to the db.

How do I avoid having to have class definitions for these objects in both main.py and scrape.py?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the classes in a separate module (file) and `import` them in both of the other files.

**models.py** (new file)

```
class MyModel(object):
    pass # Implementation here
```

**scrape.py** or **main.py**

```
from models import MyModel, SomeOtherModel
m = MyModel
m.put()
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a seperate .py file called something like classes and variables, place all classes you use in your code in that file and call it upon startup for both files.